# Routes em CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar rotas no CodeIgniter.No momento,tudo que consigo sao rotas do tipo " **www.site.com/index.php/pagina2** ".

Gostaria de criar rotas como " **www.site.com/pagina2** "

Já tentei usar o tutorial da documentação do CodeIgniter 3

" **$route['pagina2'] = 'controlador_pagina2';** " no arquivo de rotas e nada....

Acho que são chamadas rotas magicas na comunidade do Code.

Alguem saberia ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618633/routes-in-codeigniter-automatically

Comment: Talvez este link possa ajuda-lo: http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/rotas-no-codeigniter-do-inicio-ao-fim/

Comment: Não é duplicado,esté topico está no stackoverflow americano,esse é PT.

Já olhei esse tutorial e fiz exatamente igual,porem não funcionou nao :/

Vou dar uma olhada nesse topico que você me disse!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minha versão do codeigniter é mais antiga que a atual. então.... Mas segue o exemplo:

altere seu htaccess para:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove /index/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Remove trailing slashes (prevents duplicate SEO issues)
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # If not a file or directory, route everything to CI
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] # This is an alternative

</IfModule>
```

No teu config:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.seusite.com/";
# or use $config['base_url'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

e no teu Routes: (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html)

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['product/(:any)'] = "tuaconfig/action";
$route['404_override'] = "";
```

Caso sua versão seja a atual, eu vi na documentação atual ( https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html )e seguindo ela :
Na raiz do framework:

```
application/
assets/
system/
.htaccess
index.php
```

Em seguida alterar o arquivo application/config/config.php:

```
  $config['index_page'] = "index.php";
    $config['index_page'] = "";
```

Comment: Irei configurar desta tal forma e logo retorno com a resposta.Desde já,agradeço a atenção!

Comment: fiz uma edição colocando link para melhor você poder entender pela explicação do manual

Comment: Deu certo aqui,estou dando uma estudada melhor na documentação.Estava desenvolvendo um sistema em Rails 5,tudo pronto.E descobri depois de pronto que a hospedagem do cliente não suporta Ruby e nada faz com que ele mude de hospedagem.E tive que migrar para o PHP de uma hora pra outra...

Comment: de boa... Vai dá tudo certo. Sucesso