# Rotas CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Galera a rota padrão do site é "http://localhost/" ou "http://localhost/index.php"

quando vou acessar a pagina de login por exemplo,gostaria de acessar "http://localhost/login" e não "http://localhost/index.php/login" como o codeiginiter obriga...

Tem como mudar isso?

**.htacess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**arquivo config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

**arquivo routes está padrão**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Controler, nome "**Login**"

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('index');
}
```

e a **View** está dentro de uma pasta "**login**" que tem dentro um "**entrar.php**"

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Routes em CodeIgniter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305431/routes-em-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma configuração na pasta `application/config` no arquivo `config.php` que deve esta configurado da seguinte forma:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

mas, o seu servidor deve estar configurado o modulo de reescrita de url.

Uma observação, se estiver utilizando Xampp deve estar mau configurado, então, utilize o servidor embutido do PHP, configurando as variaveis de ambiente do sistema e digitando `php -S localhost:8989` tem um servidor rodando nessa porta (que pode variar de computado pra computador) é um servidor pra teste que já vem com o `PHP` ([A partir do PHP 5.4.0, o CLI SAPI fornece um servidor web embutido.](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php)) que funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Ja está configurado de tal forma e o mudulo tambem.Alguma outra possibilidade? Obrigado ate o momento!

Comment: Não se não está funcionando preciso ver o que está no seu arquivo login e como está suas pastas e também tem se você seguiu a nomenclatura de nomes! Tem como colocar isso na sua pergunta @HigorLamonier ???

Comment: Editei com algumas informações nas quais acho que você queira saber!

Comment: Cade o `controller` Login @HigorLamonier ??? Voce está rodando APACHE?

Comment: Controller Login é o mesmo do Welcome,padrão,porem devidamente alterado...Desculpa coloquei o errado...Sim,porem atraves do XAMP

Comment: Se você digitar : `http://localhost/index.php/login` funciona?

Comment: Sim,funciona.Mas sem o "index.php" nao vai,da "Objeto nao encontrado,erro 404"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79617/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-higor-lamonier).